# pubnub integration in react js frontend and nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pubnub

i want to integrate pubnub with reactjs frontend and node js backend.My system consist of websocket . I want to replace websocket with pubnub connection .I have installed pubnub using npm in node js its works fine.But in front end side when i run npm start  i see only below screen.

[image]

The problem with web socket is when connection lost i didnt get back my card details(poker game cards)
Did i do something wrong?if please let me know correct way to do it.
i have replaced websocket connection of existing system with pubnub.see code below.

```
import PubNub from 'pubnub';
import { PubNubProvider, usePubNub } from 'pubnub-react';
// import CountDownBgTask from "./containers/CountDownBgTask";
const pubnub = new PubNub({
   publishKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   subscribeKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});
componentDidMount() {
        if (isMobile) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    isOpen: true
                });
                window.scrollTo(0,1);
            },1000)
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
        // Read res from service via Socket IO
        // socket.on("message", receiveMsg);
        pubnub.on("message", text => {
            let params = text.split("|"); //.map(p => Base64.Decode(p)); // we are not using b64 now
            let message = params.shift(); // message, eg. playerSitOut, clearTable

            this.receiveMsg.push(message);
            this.props.updateMessage({ message, params });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any "subscribe" to channel. Right now, you are not connected to any channel and therefore, no socket/connection. See this link for more details and let me know if that helps: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/react#add-event-listeners